# Integral of $y^3 \sin^2 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have the following problem, integrate $\int_B y^3 \sin^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ where $B$ is the set between $y^2 = 1-z$, $x=0$, $x=4$, $z=0$.

I have tried to solve the problem using spherical and cylindrical coordinates but the resulting integral is quite complicated. Is there any transformation resulting in a more reasonable integral? The problem advises to take into account the "simmetry" of the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume integral is

$$\int_0^4\int_{-1}^{1} y^3 [\sin^2(x^2+y^2+(1-y^2)^2)
-\sin^2(x^2+y^2)]
dydx $$

Note that the integrand is odd in $y$ over its integration limit $y\in [-1,1]$, which makes the integral vanishing.

Answer (score 2):

The integral is $0$ because the integrand function is odd in $y$ and the integration set is even in $y$.